# Dynamic Unobserved Effects models and the FE vs RE disscussion

Tags: panel-data, econometrics

I have estimated a DUEM model estimated as a RE with GLS of the forum

Yit = a + BXit + Yit-1 +Ci + ui

where u is an error and ci is unobserved heterogeneity, X is a vector of covariates. Under this model according to Wooldridge text Ci and Xit are allowed to be arbitrarily correlated. and uit to be correlated with future values of the explanatory variables. In this model, does the distinction between RE and FE still matter?

For example if the hausman test states its FE and this model is run would i have biased results?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always better to use Fixed Effects unless you are interested in intercepts in the regression. If Hausman test FE, then I would go for FEs. 
Also you may check, correlated random effects models, which is in between REs and FEs.